# Dropped computer. Will not boot. Unable to find driver for this platform \“ACPI\” MACOSX version

Tags: hard-drive

I dropped my computer two days ago. At first it would not boot up at all, not even showing the grey circle with the line in it or anything at all. I did internet recovery and did some cleaning up of the hard drive but it was saying I had problems with the partition boot. It was giving me some screen saying "Unable to find driver for this platform" after booting though. I went back into internet recovery, erased the drive, and re-installed os x. It was giving me the same error at first, but then I started it in safe mode and it worked. I restarted it normally and it worked.

Did dropping it break my hard drive or some other part in my computer? It seems to be working fine now, but I can't trust it. Is there any software that I can use to run some hard ware diagnostics?

EDIT: Macbook Pro 13' 2012 version. I had Mac OS X Mavericks, but currently it is back at OS X Lion. My computer will occasionally hang with the beach ball for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably run 2 tests.

The Disk Utility Test (does not require restart).

Disk Utility.app is located in your Utility folder, use it to check the hard disk.

and the [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781). (does require restart)